# How to put two different filters on a table in a Cognos Dashboard

Tags: filter, dashboard, cognos

I'm working on a dashboard using Cognos.  I have one number that I want to put two different filters on then divide one by the other.  But I can't seem to find a way to have different filters on each number. Any calculation I make puts the numbers under the same filter so when I divide A/B I gives me 1.

Comment: Could you rewrite the question to make it clearer what you are attempting and what you are experiencing pls.  Use pictures if you need to.   Scrub sensitive data from the pictures.

Comment: Is it possible to use Framework Manager to create a data item with the calculation you want?  This way you can just add it to the dashboard?

Comment: An if then else construct should allow you to condition the same number in two different ways before doing the division.